# Definition of unit normal vector

Tags: geometry, vectors

Given any $k$-flat, how can you generalize a unit normal vector $\hat{n}$? Would it be that given the flat in dimension $ k$, $\hat{n}_k > 0$? What if the flat had a rotation so that $\hat{n}_k = 0$, giving two solutions?

As a recap, how do you generalize any unit normal vector normal to a flat?

Answer (score 0):

Given a $k$-flat (also called a $k$-dimensional affine subspace) of $\Bbb{R}^n$, the perpendicular subspace is $(n - k)$-dimensional.  The set of all unit *normal* vectors to the $k$-flat forms an $(n - k - 1)$-dimension sphere.  (The set of unit vectors in an $m$-dimensional space is always a sphere of dimension of $m - 1$.)

In the special case $k = n - 1$, the $k$-flats are called hyperplanes and the perpendicular space is $1$-dimensional (a line); hence the set of unit normal vectors forms a $0$-sphere (two points), which is why you have a choice of two possible normal directions.

Once $n - k > 1$, the perpendicular space has more than $1$ dimension, and so there is a continuum of possible unit normal vectors.  For example, when $k = n - 2$, there is a $2$-dimensional perpendicular space; hence the set of unit normal vectors forms a $1$-sphere (circle).  Think about a line in $\Bbb{R}^3$.  Every point has a "circle's worth" of perpendicular directions in the ambient space.

Comment: So, for $\hat{n}_k = 0$, $\hat{n}$ would actually be $\pm \hat{n}$?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by $\hat{n} = 0$.  Doesn't $\hat{n}$ signify a normal vector of unit magnitude?  In otherwords, $\hat{n} \cdot \vec{x} = 0$ for all $\vec{x}$ in the $k$-flat (**normal**) and $\| \hat{n} \| = 1$ (**unit**).

Comment: $\hat{n}_k$ is the length of $\hat{n}$ in the $k$-th dimension, treating it like a matrix.

Comment: Oh, I misread that.  Sorry.  The projection of the unit normal along *any* direction can be zero, including $k$th coordinate direction $(0, \ldots, 1, \ldots, 0)$.

Comment: Though, what I mean is, in order for it to be a NORMAL vector, the $\hat{n}$ in dimension $k$ MUST BE greater than or 0, or else there are two solutions defined $\pm \hat{n}$... right?

Comment: There are far more than two possible normal vectors.  The set of all possible normal vectors forms a sphere!  In the hyperplane case $k = n - 1$, there are only two possible vectors (as you describe).  This is the $0$-sphere.